# View Linux Kernel Config Options

Tags: linux, kernel, config, fedora

Is it possible to view which flags were used during kernel compilation?
2.6.42.12-1 fedora 15.

I am sure I've done this before but I can't find anything on google (ie i look for wrong thing :/ ).

Comment: possible same on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/287371/obtain-kernel-config-from-currently-running-linux-system

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Current kernel config:

```
cat /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

Other installed kernels:

```
ls /boot/config-*
```

Answer (score 22):

```
cat /proc/config.gz | gunzip
```

if kernel was compiled with corresponding option (usually it is)

Comment: what is that "corresponding option"?

Comment: `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC=y`